# Woocommerce update fee on shipping method change

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have an eshop with 2 shipping methods and 3 payment gateways. I managed to configure their dependencies, so they work as follows:

1. *local_pickup* allows for "cop" only
2. *wbs* allows for "cod" and "bacs"
3. "cod" is available only for my country, so for others *wbs* allows for "bacs" only

"cod" has a fixed additional fee, which is applied correctly when I click on "cod". When I switch payment from "cod" to "bacs", fee is removed from cart as expected. The problem occurs when customer has "cod" selected and switches from *wbs* to *local_pickup* or when he switches the coutry while "cod" is selected. The cart is refreshed, but the fee is still present. I tried to set empty array for `$woocommerce->session->fees`, but it doesn't  help. I feel it's caused by session values that are not updated, because on browser refresh the fee disappears.

Here is my code both for payment gateways conditions and for extra fee:

```
function wc_local_available_payment_gateways( $gateways ) {
  global $woocommerce;
  $chosen_shipping_rates = $woocommerce->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods' );
  $country = $woocommerce->customer->get_country();

  if($country == "SK") {
    $method = (is_array($chosen_shipping_rates)) ? $chosen_shipping_rates : 
    array($chosen_shipping_rates);
    if (in_array('local_pickup:1', $chosen_shipping_rates )) {
        unset( $gateways['bacs'] );
        unset( $gateways['cod'] );
    }
  }
  else {
    unset( $gateways['cod'] );
  }
  return $gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'wc_local_available_payment_gateways' );

function add_extra_cart_fee( $cart_object ) {
  global $woocommerce;
  $payment = $woocommerce->session->get('chosen_payment_method');
  $spfee = 0.60;
  if($payment == "cod") $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Extra fee', $spfee, false );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_extra_cart_fee' ,10,1 );

function print_autoload_js(){
  ?><script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $(document.body).on('change', 'input[name="payment_method"]', function() {
      $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
      $.ajax( $fragment_refresh );
    });
    $(document.body).on('change', 'input[name="shipping_method"]', function() {
      $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
      $.ajax( $fragment_refresh );
    });
   });
  </script><?php 
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_submit' , 'print_autoload_js');
```

Comment: I just answered my question, but I am still open to an alternative way of fixing this behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after struggling with this issue, I came to a quite simple solution that is a bit of "dirty hack", but it works so here we go..

Firstly, the jQuery code was taken from a plugin used for "Pay for Payment" fees. Later I realized, that `$.ajax` part is not needed and it's not working at all :)

Secondly, the `shipping_method` part was added to trigger the cart refresh when I removed the plugin, as the fee can be added by a small function. Later I realized, it doesn't work, because the input name is `shipping_method[0]` (that's why the shipping method is always an array while payment gateway is a string)

Lastly, after combining all the findings, I came to a solution where I simply "fake" the payment gateway before the cart is refreshed, so Woocommerce thinks the correct gateway is selected (while in fact it doesn't exist in current view) and removes the fee for `cod` gateway.

```
$(document.body).on('change', 'input[name="shipping_method[0]"], #shipping_country, #billing_country', function() {
  if($('#shipping_method_0_local_pickup1').is(':checked')) {
    $('#payment_method_bacs').val('cp').prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```